# Generate one Viewer file from two design files on Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

Using Autodesk Forge Viewer

I want to generate one viewer file from two IFC files with the Forge API.Can I do that with the Model Derivative API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can translate “composed” files (e.g., assembly and part files in Inventor, or XREFs in AutoCAD): https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-composite-source-file-to-stl.

Alternatively, you could translate your IFC files separately and load them both into the viewer: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/supporting-multiple-models-new-modelstructurepanel.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I tyied your two methods.  In the translate "composed" files method,I can use "unlinked" two files?Or only "linked" file.

Comment: The composed method requires that you define the "root" file, and the translation will take care of all additional files linked from the root file. If there are additional files in the zip archive that are not referenced by the root file in any way, the translation will ignore them.

Comment: I got it.I find that root file and the additional file in Viewer.Thank you.